# React Django app not updating component after change

Tags: reactjs, django

I was working on a react js app with django backend. I made some changes to my search page component but my browser is still rendering the old search page. Here is the code for my search page

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import axios from 'axios';

const SearchPage = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState(null);
  const [recentSearches, setRecentSearches] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedSearches = localStorage.getItem('recentSearches');
    if (storedSearches) {
      const parsedSearches = JSON.parse(storedSearches);
      console.log("Loaded searches:", parsedSearches);
      setRecentSearches(parsedSearches);
    } else {
      console.log("No recent searches found in localStorage");
    }
  }, []); 

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/backend/search', {
        headers: {
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        },
        params: {
          searchTerm: searchTerm,
          start: 0, 
        },
      });
      setSearchResults(response.data);
      if (searchTerm.trim() !== '') {
        const updatedSearches = [searchTerm, ...recentSearches.filter(search => search !== searchTerm).slice(0, 4)];
        setRecentSearches(updatedSearches);
        localStorage.setItem('recentSearches', JSON.stringify(updatedSearches));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data: ', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ margin: "20px" }}>
        <TextField
          label="Enter search term"
          variant="standard"
          fullWidth
          onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div style={{ margin: "20px" }}>
        <h3>Recent Searches:</h3>
        <ul>
          {recentSearches.map((search, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{search}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button style={{ margin: "20px" }} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleSearch}>
          Search
        </Button>
      </div>
      {searchResults ? (
        <div>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(searchResults, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div style={{ margin: "20px" }}>
          <p>Enter text to search</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchPage;
```

It happened to me before. I restarted my system and the problem got solved. But this time I have tried everything but still it's not working. I also cleared browser cache but still the issue persists. It does not even give any output to the browser console.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the page in incognito mode or using a different browser to see if the issue persists. This can help rule out browser-specific problems.
OR
I think the better ,If you're deploying your Django backend and React frontend separately, make sure that you've deployed the latest versions of both  and  clear Server-Side Caching...
I hope these solutions have helped you..

Comment: I had to delete all the cookies on my browser. Then it worked.